# Subsetting with base R

Tags: r

I want to satisfy two conditons in the mtcars data set.

- CYL needs to equal 4 and CARB needs to be less than 2
- HP needs to be greater than 100 or MPG needs to be greater than 30

The following expression does not get me there. Because the following syntax is wrong. What's the correct syntax? I know how to accomplish this properly with dplyr but want to learn how to do this with base R.

```
subset(mtcars, 
  cyl == 4 & 
  carb < 2 & 
  hp > 100 | 
  mpg > 30
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the parenthesis in your code. Its like this

```
subset(mtcars, 
       (cyl == 4 & 
         carb < 2) & 
         (hp > 100 | 
         mpg > 30)
)
```

Comment: Correct, otherwise the test is "all of the first 3 conditions OR ONLY the last condition".